# How to run Django app with Apache2, mod_wsgi and Anaconda?

Tags: python, django, apache, anaconda, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run a django application with Apache2, wsgi_mod, Anaconda environment with Python3.8 in Ubuntu.

When I run 'sudo service apache2 start' , the page keeps re-loading and the same error message is stacking at '/var/log/apache2/error.log'.

```
Current thread 0x00007ff7b9507bc0 (most recent call first):
[Thu Apr 02 20:02:27.236780 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24024:tid 140701942709184] AH00051: child pid 29871 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 02 20:02:27.237711 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24024:tid 140701942709184] AH00051: child pid 29872 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

These are the sys.prefix and the sys.path

```
(my_env) manager@ubserv01:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env
(my_env) manager@ubserv01:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python38.zip', '/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8', '/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

This is the mod_wsgi-express module-config output:

```
(my_env) manager@ubserv01:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ mod_wsgi-express module-config
LoadModule wsgi_module "/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env"
```

Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/djangoProject.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /var/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

WSGIPythonHome /var/anaconda3/envs/my_env

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName opes.com
    ServerAdmin admin
    LogLevel warn
    DocumentRoot /var/www/opes/djangoProject

      <Directory /var/www/opes/djangoProject/djangoProject>
         <Files wsgi.py>
             Require all granted
         </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess djangoProject python-path=/var/www/opes/djangoProject python-home=/var/anaconda3/envs/my_env
    WSGIProcessGroup djangoProject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/opes/djangoProject/djangoProject/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/djangoProject"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/djangoProject" common
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/opes/djangoProject is the directory where manage.py is located.
I enable this file with: sudo a2ensite

And the wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append("/var/www/opes/djangoProject")
sys.path.append("/var/www/opes/djangoProject/djangoProject")

os.environ.setdefault("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8")
os.environ.setdefault("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangoProject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I installed mod_wsgi with: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and I enable it whit: sudo a2enmod wsgi.

I don't know how this really work, it's seems to be a problem with the virtual environment, but I'm quite confused. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, but I really recommend Nginx + Gunicorn with Anaconda as environment

Check it out.

My git --> [Nginx + Gunicorn](https://github.com/Nouvellie/ubuntu/blob/ubuntu/contents/nginx.md)

Comment: I follow your advice and it's working now, thanks bro!